# Jq: How to select an object if the object has an array of objects, that have a key with a value that does not match?

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON object that I want to extract with Jq:

```
{
"key_1": "uo2",
"key_2": false,
"measurements": [
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_P"
    },
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_3"
    },
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_001"
    }
],
"key_3": "bwr",
"key_4": null,
"key_5": 31066.0
}
```

Now I want to select this object, if the array measurements has an object that has key_c=="Value 3", as long as it does not have any object that has key_c=="Value 4". The object above should be selected, but not the one below.

```
{
"key_1": "uo2",
"key_2": false,
"measurements": [
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_4"
    },
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_P"
    },
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_3"
    },
    {
        "key_a": null,
        "key_b": 37.5,
        "key_c": "Value_001"
    }
],
"key_3": "bwr",
"key_4": null,
"key_5": 31066.0
}
```

The array measurements can be of any length, and is not sorted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a filter like this one

```
def condition1: any(.key_c == "Value_3");
def condition2: any(.key_c == "Value_4") | not;
select(.measurements|condition1 and condition2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZHLCoMwEEX3@YqQlYJIfLWg@A9ddVOKRJ2CbYzUB0XUb7eJfWmhuzqLwL1zc2ZIztdxTOGEk0KkWZ0VwvIxE61mXqCNEhyGmOwZbyByiB6gRdL@kXSJjnssijpAFXBIas3MgVVNCTmIuuo/o@T9dMbTx7FDROEs4mPSFDYxHtqW@sR4BVLPWdI@ICyrm05VU57Jhmg4N5Z2LG1na3pfdqKmvXafWoPxV@puFaqzCpVS68lFx@frO6ob38rXb7hv9iQ9xbToZmNSNNwB)

Answer (score 0):

As a scrunched one-liner:

```
select(.measurements|any(.key_c=="Value_3") and all(.key_c!="Value_4"))
```